# Using Django 1.8 with Shibboleth

Tags: python, django, shibboleth

I'm working on a project with my University that I will eventually need to integrate with the Shibboleth system that the University uses. I'm using Django 1.8, and I'm looking for a way that I could simply integrate basic authentication within the application.

I've seen a few packages that supposedly do this but I haven't had any luck finding something compatible with 1.8. Even the questions asked before on SO haven't been entirely relevant to what I need.

Any help with recommending a package, or somewhere to start on creating my own backend for Shibboleth would be most welcome!

Answer (score 1):

I would begin by installing the Shibboleth Service Provider (SP) on your server and integrating Apache HTTPD with the mod_shibd module.

https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/Installation

Comment: Thank you for your response, but installing and configuring the sever for shibboleth is not my issue at the moment. The server is already set up and installed via. the University's standards. My issue the communication point between the django application and the service provider itself.